# Manually applying the ngModel directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

My directive needs to use `ngModel`.

I need to do this dynamically from within another directive as I want to do some funky stuff with scopes and abstract this away from the person writing the HTML.

My first thought was to use the `$set` function provided by the `attrs` argument in the `link` function, that works to modify the HTML but the directive itself does not get compiled. We can then combine this with the `$compile` provider, and it works.

```
attrs.$set('ngModel', someVar);
$compile(element)(scope);
```

The problem is that this creates infinite recursion if I do not (and I can not) replace the elements tag as the directive gets reapplied and recompiled indefinitely.

However I can fiddle with the priorities and get that to work:

```
module.directive('input', [
  '$compile',
  function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      priority: 100, // Set this high enough to perform other directives
      terminal: true, // Make sure this is the last directive parsed
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var key = 'example';
          attrs.$set('ngModel', key);
          $compile(element, null, 100)(scope);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

This works fine, but it just feels wrong:

- I now have to ensure that all other directives on the element are
  capable of being recompiled as they will all get compiled twice.
- I have to make sure that nobody uses a higher priority.

So this got me thinking why can't I just inject the ngModelDirective and force compile it against my element?

```
module.directive('input', [
  'ngModelDirective',
  function(ngModel) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      priority: 100, // Set this high enough to perform other directives
      terminal: true, // Make sure this is the last directive parsed
      require: '?^form',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
          var key = 'example';
          attrs.$set('ngModel', key);
          var ngModelFactory = ngModel[0];
          var ngModelLink = ngModelFactory.compile(element);
          ngModelLink.call(this, scope, element, attrs, [ngModelFactory.controller, formCtrl]);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

*See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1356*

No errors thrown, but nothing happens. It seems this isn't enough to hook it up, so my question is can anyone elaborate on to what I need to do link the `ngModelDirective` to my custom directive without forcing a recompile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do it. It's not the prettiest thing but it works and I can hook up my `input` directive to work using the native `inputDirective` so that it can use things like `require` or validate specific input types.

To build this against another standard directive that implements specific `ngModel` functionality such as `ngChange` just replace the injected `inputDirective` with the correct directive e.g., `ngChangeDirective`.

```
module.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    require: '?ngModel',
    priority: -1,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      var key = 'example.property';

      if (ngModel === undefined) {
        attrs.$set('ngModel', key);
        angular.injector(['ng']).invoke([
          'inputDirective',
          'ngModelDirective',
          '$controller',
          '$exceptionHandler',
          '$parse',
          '$animate',
          function(inputDirective, ngModelDirective, $controller, $exceptionHandler, $parse, $animate) {
            var ngModelFactory = ngModelDirective[0];
            var ngModelLink = ngModelFactory.compile(scope); // Get the ngModel linkage function against this scope
            ngModel = $controller(ngModelFactory.controller, {
              $scope: scope,
              $exceptionHandler: $exceptionHandler,
              $attrs: attrs,
              $element: element,
              $parse: $parse,
              $animate: $animate
            }); // Call the ngModel controller and bootstrap it's arguments
            // Call the inputDirective linkage function to set up the ngModel against this input
            inputDirective[0].link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel);
            element.data('$ngModelController', ngModel); // Allow additional directives to require ngModel on this element.
          }
        ]);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**NOTE:** This will not work for `ngOptions` as it specifies `terminal: true`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible without a re-compile.

The `ngModel` is designed to be a kind of collaborator between other directives in the same element and also parent form diretives. For example, during complilation:

- other directives (e.g. input, required or ng-change) may add its own `$parser` or `$formatter` to ngModel.
- ngModel will add itself to a parent form directive if exists.

Therefore, if the `ngModel` is somehow added after the complication process is ended already, the above two actions will be missing.

**Edit:** In case the value to be assigned to ng-model attribute is **known at the compile time**, it is possible and will be something like this:

```
app.directive('myNgModel', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true, // these terminal and priority will stop all other directive from being compiled.
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var key = 'example';

      attrs.$set('ngModel', key);
      attrs.$set('myNgModel', null); // remove itself to avoid a recusion

      $compile(element)(scope); // start compiling other directives
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the plunker with example: http://plnkr.co/edit/S2ZkiVIyq2bOK04vAnFO?p=preview

Comment: Just to let you know I managed to solve this (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808480/718728)). +1 For pointing out the stuff about the directive specific linkages. I would of struggled without knowing that beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

`ngModel` seems a bad fit for what you are trying to do. But you don't need it anyway. You can two-way-bind some variable and pass the name into the model directive scope:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    // ...
    scope: {
        myModel = "=",
        modelName = "myModel"
        // ...
    }
    // ...
});

app.directive("ngModelDirective", function() {
    // ...
    // ...
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var modelName = scope.modelName;
        console.assert(modelName, '`modelName` must be set when using `ngModelDirective`.');
        // TODO: Check if `scope[modelName]` is actually bound
        doSomethingFancyWith(scope, modelName);
    }
});
```

Template example:

```
<myDirective ngModelDirective my-model="..." />
```

Note that `doSomethingFancyWith` can read and write the model variable, with bindings to the outside world.

Comment: The reason I want `ngModel` is it allows the user to extend it without knowing my syntax, it also increases the chance that other peoples code plays well with it. Plus I need to use `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` down the line. I agree in a closed environment I could probably write a more efficient solution, but this is for a library.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Did you consider manually implementing it, by simply copying (some of) the source code of [ngModel](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1992) and [NGModelController](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1400)?

Comment: Just to let you know I found a working solution (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808480/718728)) +1 for your help.